# Debugging JavaScript using WebStorm for a CEF application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm, chromium-embedded, javascript-debugger

I have an application that uses [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) to display HTML web views that are served from disk. Using CEF we are able to open the debugger in Chrome using an URL that is given by CEF. In example, CEF returns the URL `http://localhost:9088/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:9088/devtools/page/b52a00728493b15d40c8c9e7b32c2b10` that we can open in Chrome to debug the running code using similar Chrome debugging environment.

That said, I was wondering if it would be possible to do the same debugging but in WebStorm using some kind of remote debugging feature. I guess that `http://localhost:9088` is a embedded HTTP server that CEF creates to be able to serve the devtools to debug the views, so would it be possible to connect to it through WebStorm?

If that would be possible that would be a great gain, since we could edit and debug in the same editor.

Comment: if you know the URL CEF uses you can specify it in javascript debug run configuration and then use it to run your application on CEF server

Answer (score 0):

Good new, JetBrains added support for Chromium remote debugging in WebStorm 9!

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11968

Currently it only supports a single view/page in your CEF process but that is a good start.